# What is this measuring tool for?

Tags: woodworking, tools

[image]

[image]

I was going though my dad's and his dad's tools and found this tool. The two iron pins can go up and down and be locked by the screws.

Is it a measuring tool? How do you use it?

Comment: Perhaps a depth gauge for bored holes, center and edge (because a drill bit is cone shaped)? Or for piton or valve stroke? What were your father's hobbies?

Comment: Would say to copy or compare a measurement  of one thing to another.

Answer (score 42):

## Dual marking or cutting gauge

Used for marking mortise and tenon joints. The yellow disk in the illustration below is the fence, corresponding to the disk shaped (hockey puck shaped) fence of OP's tool. The sharp edge of the marking disks scribe the workpiece. In some gauges the cutting disks rotate freely, and they are called marking wheels.

[image]

> With two independently adjustable rods, this gauge lets you set two measurements at once, so you can quickly alternate between them when transferring or marking repetitive dimensions.

The one shown below in the pic also has an optional shaft clamp (not shown) that locks to both shafts and will allow you to keep the relative position of the shafts while shifting the fence (the large disk shown in the pic)

https://www.leevalley.com/en-us/shop/tools/hand-tools/marking-and-measuring/marking-gauges/67466-veritas-dual-marking-gauge

[image]

Comment: I agree. My grandfather was a carpenter specialized in cabinetry and fine furniture. It was 45 years ago, but I still remember seeing him use one of these to measure out mortise and tenon joints.

Comment: For example of use you can see almost any of [Matt Estlea's videos](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCxWzA3ZlYEOLr1JkKH0ZMyg/videos) on dove tail making, or [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7G1Kmfb51Q) where he specifically talks about marking guages.

Answer (score 0):

The carpenter uses it to draw two double lines with a specific spacing, before digging a channel into the wood, to insert a recess or install a latch, for example.  I've seen similar model with tapered heads as well that are good for tracing lines as well.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Home Improvement SE. Unfortunately, it looks like your answer doesn't add much to the other answer here. Consider expanding it, perhaps adding a picture of the "model with tapered heads" and explaining exactly how it is used.